# Setting initial state to null and passing file object to preview modal

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am creating a preview modal to view a specific image on click. My thought process is to have a state property set to null, on clicking the image I then set the state to the specific file and render the image path as the image source. However, Typescript does not like this and states `Object is possibly null`.

- I tried adding `selectedFile: Asset` in my extended props but I am given an error in the parent component expecting it to pass the file down. I do not want it to behave this way.
- I tried writing it as `selectedFile: Asset<{}>()` but Typescript complains that I'm using it as a type instead of a value.

```
import * as React from "react"
import { Company } from "data/companies"
import { Asset } from "data/companies"
import Modal from "components/Modal"

interface MediaLibraryProps {
  company: Company
}

class MediaLibrary extends React.Component<MediaLibraryProps> {
  state = {
    mediaLibrary: [],
    editModalIsOpen: false,
    selectedFile: null
  }

  toggleEditModal = () => {
    this.setState({ editModalIsOpen: !this.state.editModalIsOpen })
  }

  openEditModal = (file: Asset) => {
    this.setState({
      editModalIsOpen: true,
      selectedFile: file
    })
  }

  getMediaLibrary = async () => {
    await fetch(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_SA_API_URL}/${this.props.company.id}/images`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
        },
      }
    ).then(blob => blob.json())
      .then(function (data: any) {
        return data.map((file: Asset) => Object.assign(file, {
          assetId: file.assetId,
          path: file.path
        }))
      }).then((data) => this.setState({ mediaLibrary: [...data] }))
  }

  render() {
    const files = this.state.mediaLibrary.map((file: Asset) => (
      <div key={file.assetId} onClick={() => this.openEditModal(file)}>
        <div>
          <img src={`${process.env.REACT_APP_SA_CDN_URL}${file.path}`} />
        </div>
      </div>
    ))

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h2>Media Library</h2>
        </div>
        {files}
        <hr />
        <Modal isOpen={this.state.editModalIsOpen} toggleOpenness= 
          {this.toggleEditModal}>
          <img
            src={this.state.selectedFile.path}
            onClick={this.toggleEditModal}
          />
        </Modal>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MediaLibrary
```

- I expect the file to be passed to the state and be given access to its properties to be used in my Modal.
- Actual behaviour is that TypeScript does not like a state to be initialized as null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do this but I fixed it by setting

```
state = {
    selectedFile: {
      path: ""
    }
  }

openEditModal = (file: Asset) => {
    this.setState({
      editModalIsOpen: true,
      selectedFile: {
        path: file.path
      }
    })
  }
```